# Column size in jOOQ

Tags: sql, jooq

Using `ResultSet` I can get `ResultSetMetaData` from which I can get size of the database column in characters (for example 15 for `varchar(15)`) using `metaData.getColumnDisplaySize(index)`. Is it any way I can get this size using `jOOQ`?

With `ResultSet` I have problem with UDT and I am already using `jOOQ` for access to database (and it works well with UDT) so it would be perfect if yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meta information that you're looking for is not provided by jOOQ 2.x APIs. Adding length, precision, and scale to the `org.jooq.DataType` API is planned for the upcoming release 3.0

This is registered as feature request [#456](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/456)

---

As a matter of fact, this is now implemented on github, and will be included in jOOQ 3.0. The API usage needed to achieve what you're looking for will look like this (an example):

```java
int length = record.getField(0).getDataType().length();
```

In essence, `org.jooq.DataType` will have these three methods:

```java
int length();
int precision();
int scale();
```